# autocomplete with datatables

Tags: jquery, datatable, autocomplete

I am working in **codeigniter framework**. I used datatables for sorting, fitering, pagination etc. For that in my view page i have

```
    table class="table table-bordered datatable" id="table_export"
```

and the script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{


    var datatable = $("#table_export").dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
```

with this line i get the search and all along with its styles. But the problem is i want to implement an autocomplete for the search button. Is there any option to implement autocomplete in datatables? Since i feel much difficult to edit the datatables's `jquery`.

Any suggetions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: once go through this site, it may help you->http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/  and https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf

Comment: but in most of the tutorials, autocomplete is done with a search box. Here we have search box in the jquery file. after searching, entire table is returned.

Comment: any sample using autocomplete in datatables?? anywhere?

Comment: yea will show u an example

Comment: check this, sample-> http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~cs387/yui/examples/datatable/dt_autocomplete.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure , whether this is what u want, just an example that how autcomplete is used in datatable.just set enable_auto_complete: true in relevant columns (in the below code column_number : 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#example').dataTable().yadcf([
  {column_number : 0},
  {column_number : 1, filter_container_id: "external_filter_container"},
  {column_number : 2, data:["Yes","No"], filter_default_label: "Select Yes/No"},
  {column_number : 3, text_data_delimiter: ",", enable_auto_complete: true},
  {column_number : 4, column_data_type: "html", html_data_type: "text", filter_default_label: "Select tag"}]);
});
```

or something like this....

```
<script>
 $("#autocompleteTable").dataTable({
  aaData : [],
  bLengthChange : false,
  bPaginate : false,
  bInfo : false,
  bFilter : false,
  aoColumns : [ {
    mDataProp : 'firstName',
    sTitle : 'First Name'
 }, {
    mDataProp : 'lastName',
    sTitle : 'Last Name'
 }, {
    mDataProp : 'address',
    sTitle : 'Address'
 } ]
});
</script>
```

for above code details check ->https://caffeinatedcoding.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/roll-your-own-autocomplete-table-with-jquery-and-datatables/

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. It works fine. But still i have some confusions. This is for a particular colomn in the table. Iam trying to implement autocomplete in a common search above the table. https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf Here in this example, we have a search above the table no? I want to implement autofilter there.  Anyways thanks for the help :)

Comment: Yeah. this one. but here too arises a problem. We have given the id of the text field. But for my case i need to give the search field's id. and search is in datatable js file

Comment: ok then call ur js like  var id=document.getElementById("searchid"), then call that id here , i think it will work

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below to add autocomplete functionality to search input box for jQuery DataTables using [typeahead.js](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) library adapted for Bootstrap 3.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var dataSrc = [];

   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      'initComplete': function(){
         var api = this.api();

         // Populate a dataset for autocomplete functionality
         // using data from first, second and third columns
         api.cells('tr', [0, 1, 2]).every(function(){
            var data = this.data();
            if(dataSrc.indexOf(data) === -1){ dataSrc.push(data); }
         });

         // Initialize Typeahead plug-in
         $('.dataTables_filter input[type="search"]', api.table().container())
            .typeahead({
               source: dataSrc,
               afterSelect: function(value){
                  api.search(value).draw();
               }
            }
         );
      }
   });
});
```

See [jQuery DataTables: Search input with autocomplete using Typeahead and Bootstrap](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-search-input-with-autocomplete-using-typeahead-and-bootstrap/) for more details and demonstration.